# Not Getting keyboard input in c kernel protected mode

Tags: c, operating-system, protected-mode, keyboardinterrupt

I am making an OS in C and 32bit Assembly following [James Molloy's tutorial](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/5.-IRQs%20and%20the%20PIT.html) till IRQs and PIT step and i am trying to get keyboard input i tried this code added to the tutorials' code but i am not able to get things right.

Keyboard.c:

```
#include "keyboard.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "monitor.h"
#include "isr.h"
//Keyboard Layout USA
unsigned char kblayout[128] =
{
    0,  27, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', /* 9 */
   '9', '0', '-', '=', '\b',    /* Backspace */
    '\t',           /* Tab */
     'q', 'w', 'e', 'r',    /* 19 */
     't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', '\n',  /* Enter key */
    0,          /* 29   - Control */
  'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', /* 39 */
 '\'', '`',   0,        /* Left shift */
 '\\', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n',            /* 49 */
  'm', ',', '.', '/',   0,              /* Right shift */
  '*',
    0,  /* Alt */
  ' ',  /* Space bar */
    0,  /* Caps lock */
    0,  /* 59 - F1 key ... > */
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,  /* < ... F10 */
    0,  /* 69 - Num lock*/
    0,  /* Scroll Lock */
    0,  /* Home key */
    0,  /* Up Arrow */
    0,  /* Page Up */
   '-',
    0,  /* Left Arrow */
    0,
    0,  /* Right Arrow */
   '+',
    0,  /* 79 - End key*/
    0,  /* Down Arrow */
    0,  /* Page Down */
    0,  /* Insert Key */
    0,  /* Delete Key */
    0,   0,   0,
    0,  /* F11 Key */
    0,  /* F12 Key */
    0,  /* All other keys are undefined */
};      


unsigned int restart_keyboard()
{    
   int data = inb(0x61);     
   outb(0x61,data | 0x80);//Disables the keyboard  
   outb(0x61,data & 0x7F);//Enables the keyboard  
   return 0;
}



unsigned char get_scancode()
{
    unsigned char inputdata;
    inputdata = inb(0x60);
    return inputdata;
}
static void keyboard_handler(registers_t regs)
{ 
     unsigned char scancode; 
     unsigned int shift_key = 0;
     scancode = get_scancode();
     if(scancode == 0x2A)     
     {  
          shift_key = 1;//Shift key is pressed
     }      
     else if(scancode & 0xAA)   
     {  
          int shift_key= 0;//Shift Key is not pressed
     }      
     else    
     {          
         if (scancode & 0x80)   
         {  
              int shiftaltctrl = 1;//Put anything to see what special keys were pressed  
         }
         else
         {   

              monitor_put(kblayout[scancode]); //Prints the character which was     pressed         
         }     
     }
}

void keyboard_install()
{
register_interrupt_handler(33, keyboard_handler);
}
```

main.c: the kernel

```
#include "monitor.h"
#include "descriptor_tables.h"
#include "timer.h"
#include "keyboard.h"

int main(struct multiboot *mboot_ptr)
{
    // Initialise all the ISRs and segmentation
    init_descriptor_tables();
    // Initialise the screen (by clearing it)
    monitor_clear();
    // Write out a sample string
    monitor_write("Hello, world!\n");
    keyboard_install();

    return 0;
}
```

All of the other files are same.
It runs ok but it does not print the output and i cant figure out why :(
I am running this with qemu.

It prints hello world but not the keystrokes

Comment: It doesn't print even "Hello, world!"? Or the actual keystrokes?

Comment: It prints hello world but not the keystrokes

Comment: off topic but that is cool that you're building your own OS.

Comment: What's off topic I don't think it is

Comment: Just to make sure it isn't something dumb - print a constant string from within the handler to isolate if you're having troubles reading the scan code or registering the interrupt

Comment: i meant my comment is off topic

Comment: Yeah wait I'm testing it

Comment: It is not printing anything on keypressi added a print in the keyboard_handler function

Comment: It does call keyboard_install but does not print anything from the keyboard_handler function I think its trouble from the interrupts

Comment: but i am getting the button press on screan but it prints another char with it ex . if i press `a`it also prints `e`with it     i think it is because of the keyboard release interrupt and i dont know how to solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was i did not restore interrupts after disabling them in the boot code for the kernel and i restored it using `asm voltile("sti")`